# PHP Create outlook/thunderbird/macbook scripts to manage email accounts

Tags: php, macos, email, outlook, thunderbird

I have no code to show for. I am trying to use PHP to create outlook,thunderbird, and macbook mail accounts. I do not mean to actually create mail accounts, but pass information that the client will use to manage an email account. I cannot find any resources on the web. Essentially, what will occur is the user will input the required information, than the PHP Script will create a file that either outlook,thunderbird,or macbook will create a new email account to manage.

Comment: outlook, thunderbird are just clients, you need account on services like gmail, yahoo, etc. SO if you want to make account without making user to register somewhere, look for api of mail services, maybe some of them will allow you to create mailbox(doubt about that, because that would allow spammers to have lots accounts)

Comment: Right. I need to figure out how to create files that the clients will read and create email accounts with, based on the parameters I set.

Comment: do you need some kind of documentation on how to create account somewhere, or you want script, with some fields, that will create account on gmail/yahoo/etc on submission of that script?

Comment: I misinterpreted what I was trying to say. Im not trying to create an email account, but create a file that the client will read and create a mail account that it will use. I updated my question.

Comment: Please add some more details, still not sure if understood you correctly

Comment: Basically, Im trying to write a PHP Script that will create a file that the client will read and create an email account to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Most mail clients use a combined preferences file to store all of their mail account information and other user preferences, such as mail rules, the interval ar which to check for new mails, and such.

What you're trying to achieve (automating the addition of an additional mail account to these clients) is really hard to do. You need to understand the format of the preference files of each of these clients, add the desired data, and make sure that you are not disturbing the existing data. A **single wrong bit** can **destroy** the whole preference file.

These files will probably differ from version to version, and possibly be encrypted (because thay may contain mail account passwords.) The information about their format may even be proprietary information and not available at all.

If that were possible by downloading and opnening a simple file, services such as Gmail or Yahoo! Mail would already create such files for you and offer them for download.